# Term for removing a graph's node while preserving paths

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

I am looking for standard terminology for the following operation on a directed graph $G=(V,E)$.

Intuitively, the operation removes a node $v$ while preserving paths via $v$, by adding edges that skip $v$.

Formally, the operation takes $G=(V,E)$ to $G'=(V',E')$ with $V'=V-\{v\}$ and $E'=\{(v_1,v_2) \in E \mid \{v_1,v_2\} \subseteq V'\} \cup \{ (v_1,v_2) \in (V')^2 \mid (v_1,v) \in E \land (v,v_2) \in E \}$.

What is the name of this operation? It sounds a lot like [edge contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_contraction), but it is not actually the same.

Comment: I would have guessed "vertex contraction", but that's [something else](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VertexContraction.html).

Comment: For an undirected graph, this is the [star-mesh transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-mesh_transform).